# Creating intervals

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

I have a data set that I would like to split into 10-day intervals. The code that I included below does that, but for the last week or so there are days that (e.g., the 31st or 30th of a month) that remain end up by itself.

I would like to either remove the intervals that create this or include them in the previous intervals.

For example:
If I separate the month of January by 10-day intervals, it would put the first 10 days in a element of a list, the second 10 days into another element and the third 10 days into another one. It would then put January 31st into a element of list by itself.

My desired output would be to either remove these elements from the list or more preferably include them in the third 10-day interval. Can that be done? If so, what would be the best way to do so?

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
date <- rep_len(seq(dmy("26-12-2010"), dmy("20-12-2013"), by = "days"), 500)
ID <- rep(seq(1, 5), 100)

df <- data.frame(date = date,
                 x = runif(length(date), min = 60000, max = 80000),
                 y = runif(length(date), min = 800000, max = 900000),
                 ID)

int <- df %>%
  arrange(ID) %>% 
  mutate(new = ceiling_date(date, '10 day')) %>% 
  # mutate(cut = data.table::rleid(cut(new, breaks = "10 day"))) %>% 
  group_by(new) %>%
  group_split()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution which splits the months by 10-day intervals but corrects `new` to assign day 31 of a month to the last period. So,

- days 1 to 10 belong to the first third of a month,
- days 11 to 20 to the second third, and
- days 21 to 31 to the third third.

```
int <- df %>%
  # arrange(ID) %>%   # skipped for readability of result
  mutate(new = floor_date(date, '10 day')) %>%
  mutate(new = if_else(day(new) == 31, new - days(10), new)) %>% 
  group_by(new) %>%
  group_split()

int[[1]]
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 6 x 5
>   date            x       y    ID new       
>   <date>      <dbl>   <dbl> <int> <date>    
> 1 2010-12-26 71469. 819084.     1 2010-12-21
> 2 2010-12-27 69417. 893227.     2 2010-12-21
> 3 2010-12-28 70865. 831341.     3 2010-12-21
> 4 2010-12-29 68322. 812423.     4 2010-12-21
> 5 2010-12-30 65643. 837395.     5 2010-12-21
> 6 2010-12-31 63638. 892200.     1 2010-12-21
> ```

Now, `2010-12-31` was assigned to the third third of December.

Note that `new` indicates the *start of the interval* by calling `floor_date()` instead of `ceiling_date()`. This is due to avoid potential problems with day arithmetic across month boundaries and to clarify to which month the interval belongs to. For instance, for the last day of February, `ceiling_date(ymd('2011-02-28'), '10 day')` returns "2011-03-03" which is a date in March.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a single row in a group give it the previous `new` value. Try this -

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  arrange(ID, date) %>% 
  mutate(new = ceiling_date(date, '10 day')) %>%
  add_count(new) %>%
  mutate(new = if_else(n == 1, lag(new), new)) %>%
  select(-n) %>%
  group_split(new)
```

---

Above would only work to combine groups that has 1 observation in a group. If we want to combine more than 1 day use the below code which counts numbers of days in a group. It combines the group if number of day is less than `n` number of days.

```
n <- 2

df %>%
  arrange(ID, date) %>% 
  mutate(new = ceiling_date(date, '10 day'), 
         ID = match(new, unique(new))) -> tmp
tmp %>%
  group_by(new, ID) %>%
  summarise(count_unique = n_distinct(date)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(new = if_else(count_unique < n, lag(new), new)) %>%
  inner_join(tmp, by = 'ID') %>%
  select(new = new.x, date, x, y) %>%
  group_split(new)
```

Comment: If there were more than one observation in the group that I would like to remove, how would I go about modifying this? Would I just change the 1 to something else? The number of observations vary between groups, in my actual data set.

Comment: That approach would only work for 1 row in a group. For more than 1 dat you may use my updated answer. @JohnHuang

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution

```r
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

dt <- rep_len(seq(dmy("26-12-2010"), dmy("20-12-2013"), by = "days"), 500)
ID <- rep(seq(1, 5), 100)

df <- data.frame(dt = dt,
  x = runif(length(dt), min = 60000, max = 80000),
  y = runif(length(dt), min = 800000, max = 900000),
  ID)
```

1. Include extra days (31st) into the last third

```r
int_df <- df %>%
  # arrange(ID) %>%
  mutate(day_date = day(dt),
    day_new = case_when(
      day_date <= 10  ~ 1,
      day_date <= 20  ~ 11,
      TRUE            ~ 21
    ),
    new = ymd(paste(year(dt), month(dt), day_new, sep = "-"))) %>% 
  select(-c(day_date, day_new)) %>% 
  group_by(new) %>%
  group_split()

int_df[[1]]
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>   dt              x       y    ID new       
#>   <date>      <dbl>   <dbl> <int> <date>    
#> 1 2010-12-26 62395. 837491.     1 2010-12-21
#> 2 2010-12-27 66236. 836481.     2 2010-12-21
#> 3 2010-12-28 79918. 818399.     3 2010-12-21
#> 4 2010-12-29 67613. 807213.     4 2010-12-21
#> 5 2010-12-30 72980. 899380.     5 2010-12-21
#> 6 2010-12-31 61004. 876191.     1 2010-12-21
```

2. Exclude extra days (31st)

```r
int_df <- df %>%
  # arrange(ID) %>%
  mutate(day_date = day(dt),
    day_new = case_when(
      day_date <= 10  ~ 1,
      day_date <= 20  ~ 11,
      day_date <= 30  ~ 21,
      TRUE            ~ 31
    ),
    new = ymd(paste(year(dt), month(dt), day_new, sep = "-"))) %>% 
  filter(day_date != 31) %>% 
  select(-c(day_date, day_new)) %>%
  group_by(new) %>%
  group_split()

int_df[[1]]
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>   dt              x       y    ID new       
#>   <date>      <dbl>   <dbl> <int> <date>    
#> 1 2010-12-26 62395. 837491.     1 2010-12-21
#> 2 2010-12-27 66236. 836481.     2 2010-12-21
#> 3 2010-12-28 79918. 818399.     3 2010-12-21
#> 4 2010-12-29 67613. 807213.     4 2010-12-21
#> 5 2010-12-30 72980. 899380.     5 2010-12-21
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>